# Is there a way to reboot windows phone 7 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to attach console windows with my windows phone 7 emulator for debugging. But i failed to reboot phone 7 emulator. Is there anyway to reboot windows phone emulator?? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just changing the region or language setting(something like that) will reboot the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the `state` data of your emulator, it should do a complete OS boot. I found my data in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\XDE`.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO shutting it down and restarting it should do the trick.